# Manually calculate robust standard errors of 2SLS regression

Tags: r, robust-standard-error, 2sls

I used the "systemfit" function in R to estimate a 2SLS model as it allows to specify the first and second stage separately which is important for my estimation. I need robust standard errors but I am having problems replicating the robust standard errors obtained when estimating the model using "iv_robust" or "ivreg" in combination with "coeftest" and vcov type "HC1".

I tried to calculate the robust standard errors manually as follows:

```
    firststagehfsystem <- H ~ HL1
    secondstageivsystem <- Index ~ H
    system = list(firststagehfsystem, secondstageivsystem)
    inst <- ~ HL1
    ivhfsystem = systemfit(system, method = "2SLS", inst = inst, data = DataControls)
    coef <- ivhfsystem$eq[[2]]$coefficients
    vcov <- ivhfsystem$eq[[2]]$coefCov
    se <- sqrt(diag(vcov))
    residuals <- ivhfsystem$eq[[2]]$residuals
    n <- nrow(DataControls)
    k <- length(coef)
    X <- model.matrix(ivhfsystem$eq[[2]])
    hc1 <- (n/(n-k))*ivhfsystem$eq[[2]]$residuals^2
    vce_hc1 <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% (hc1*diag(n)) %*% X) %*% solve(t(X) %*% X)
    sqrt(diag(vce_hc1))
```

Can anyone point out my mistake? I already googled it for days and could not find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Without having digested your code fully, doesn't `X` represent the regressors when it should be the instruments in the 2nd-to-last line?

Answer (score 0):

The `systemfit` package reverse depends the `sandwich` package which says the following about their `vcovHC` program:

> Long & Ervin (2000) conduct a simulation study of HC estimators (HC0
> to HC3) in the linear regression model, recommending to use HC3 which
> is thus the default in vcovHC.

Your by-hand approach is applying the HC1 type which will be different. This is really a question about replicating robust standard errors on a generic model fit. If you inspect the functions in `sandwich`, the `type=` argument is passed to `meatHC` as a switch with the following

```
 HC1 = {
            omega <- function(residuals, diaghat, df) residuals^2 * 
                length(residuals)/df

 HC3 = {
            omega <- function(residuals, diaghat, df) residuals^2/(1 - 
                diaghat)^2
```

Where `diaghat <- try(hatvalues(x), silent = TRUE)` is the vector of hat values from the influence function. See the referenced "Belsley, D. A., Kuh, E. and Welsch, R. E. (1980). Regression Diagnostics": if you want more detail on the calculation. R's internals use a C-subroutine that doesn't include explicit calculation  instructions.

Comment: The question is not about which standard errors to use but how to replicate them. Can you show how to manually calculate the HC3 type standard errors? When I apply coeftest using vcov type HC3 or HC1 after estimating the model via systemfit I get different standard errors compared to when I use the iv_robust or ivreg function with vcov type HC3 or HC1. How can I replicate the standard errors I get when using iv_robust or ivreg?

Comment: @JJ1214 It seemed apropos to point out why the default is different than you have calculated, and perhaps why that would be the case. Anyway, I edited the answer as much as probably is necessary.